# Flask-sqlalchemy column alias for browser output

Tags: python, flask, jinja2, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm using a for loop to output the columns and values of a single database row. This is all working but there are a couple of issues. The column names aren't suitable to output in the browser so I'm looking for a way to associate an alias (not sure this is the correct term)

eg. column names:

```
cust_name
cust_area
```

Desired output:

```
Customer name
Customer area
```

models.py

```
class Customers(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True)
    cust_name = db.Column(db.String(64))
    cust_area = db.Column(db.String(64))
    cat_id = db.Column(db.Integer(8), index = True)
```

views.py

```
customer = Customers.query.filter_by(cat_id = page).first()
test_dict = dict((col, getattr(test, col)) for col in test.__table__.columns.keys())
return render_template('test.html',
    customer = test_dict
    )
```

test.html

```
{% for key, value in customer.items() %}
    {{ key }} : {{ value }}
{% endfor %}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`info`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_8/core/schema.html#sqlalchemy.schema.Column.info) dictionary:

```py
class Customers(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    cust_name = db.Column(db.String(64), info={'name': 'Customer name'})
    cust_area = db.Column(db.String(64), info={'name': 'Customer area'})
    cat_id = db.Column(db.Integer(8), index=True)
```

Then you could iterate through columns like following:

```py
customer = Customers.query.filter_by(cat_id=page).first()
data = dict((c.info.get('name', c.name), getattr(customer, c.name))
            for c in customer.__table__.c)
# Or using dict comprehension syntax (Python 2.7+).
data = {c.info.get('name', c.name): getattr(customer, c.name)
        for c in customer.__table__.c}
```