# How to include "user friendly" column names in SQLalchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, introspection

I am trying to write a function in python, that makes some introspection on one ORM object to generate a simple html form. I get the column names, like order_name , supplier_code, etc, but I would like to assign some names like "Order Name", "Supplier Code", etc.

Is there any easy way to do it, using the SQLalchemy API?

Comment: Here's my answer to related question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16997714/1870151

Comment: Is there something missing from my answer?

Answer (score 1):

Just get the list of column names on a table and do a simple map:

```
def human_readable_cols(model_cls):
    return [' '.join(part.capitalize() for part in col.split('_'))
            for col in model_cls.__table__.columns]

print human_readable_cols(MyModel)
```

so if the columns of the model are are `['asd_asd', 'foo', 'foo_bar']`, `human_readable_cols` will return:

```
['Asd Asd', 'Foo', 'Foo Bar']
```

See also: [How to discover table properties from SQLAlchemy mapped object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2441796/how-to-discover-table-properties-from-sqlalchemy-mapped-object/2448930#2448930)